# Redirect all TLD's to .com with subfolder in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

While building my first Wordpress website I have a few issues with the URL. Since my website is multi language I have installed the Polylang plugin (Free version).

This together with permalinks seems to work.
What I have is for every language a different subfolder after the domain name:

> [www.example.com/nl/](http://www.example.com/nl/)
>
> [www.example.com/fr/contact/](http://www.example.com/fr/contact/)
>
> [www.example.com/be/page-about-info/](http://www.example.com/be/page-about-info/)

What I also try to achieve is that the domainnames with different TLD's forward to the .com domain with the folder language.

I have **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** but also **[www.example.nl](http://www.example.nl)**, **[www.example.fr](http://www.example.fr)**, **[www.example.be](http://www.example.be)** and **[www.example.de](http://www.example.de)**.

**example.nl** and **example.be** should both go to **.com/nl/**

I need to add rules to my .htaccess file but i cannot get it working. Probably because the Polylang and Wordpress also have their rules.

What i have is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.(fr|nl|de) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/%1/$1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Where this part is the part I added myself for the redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.(fr|nl|de) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/%1/$1/ [R,L]
```

I am not sure if my testing messed up my browser and the URL is being cashed but for some reason I cannot get the redirect work.

Anyone who can help me with this?

*Edit:
After testing a bit I see that for example:
https://www.example.fr/test/
works and redirects to
https://www.example.com/fr/test/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want:

```
# for as-is replacements, you can pack them in a single statement
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.(fr|nl|de) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

# for altered replacements each destination will need its own statement
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.(be|xy|etc) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/nl/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

- `R=301` issues a permanent redirect, simply `R` will issue a 302.
- `QSA` will Append the Query String, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, don't know what made the difference but it seems to work